# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on query with subqueries and EXCEPT operator

Tags: oracle, except, minus

I am getting

> `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

for the following query:

```
SELECT PEOPLE.NAME FROM
CLIENTS K INNER JOIN PEOPLE ON K.ID_L = PEOPLE.ID_L
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
(SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST.ID_U
FROM CLIENTS INNER JOIN ADORES ON CLIENTS.ID_L = ADORES.ID_L
INNER JOIN ARTIST ON ADORES.ID_U = ARTIST.ID_U
WHERE CLIENTS.ID_L = K.ID_L)

EXCEPT

(SELECT DISTINCT ARTIST.ID_U
FROM CLIENTS INNER JOIN BOUGHT ON CLIENTS.ID_L = BOUGHT.ID_L
INNER JOIN ARTWORK ON BOUGHT.ID_D = ARTWORK.ID_D
INNER JOIN ARTIST ON ARTWORK.ID_U = ARTIST.ID_U
WHERE CLIENTS.ID_L = K.ID_L)
)
```

I've checked both subqueries - both are ok. It works if I remove the `EXCEPT` operator and only use one subquery (but I need to actually test that both are equal).

Any idea on what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXCEPT` is an SQL standard that is not available in Oracle. You probably want to use the Oracle equivalent of **`MINUS`**.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557991/minus-vs-except-difference-in-oracle-sql-server) for a good answer on the two keywords.

Edit: @a_horse_with_no_name corrected thanks!

Comment: Actually `except` is defined in the SQL standard. It's not specific to SQL Server. But apart from that, you are right. `minus` is Oracle's implementation of the standard `except` operator